# Easiest way to restore old versions of Android Studio Project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I created an app way back in the day that I only deployed to private devices, it was never listed on the app store.

I needed to make some changes to it, so I opened my android studio (which has been updated to the latest version) and everything seems to have broken.

`Gradle` always fails and says:
`ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9`

I've googled this and found a widely accepted solution. I have verified `alpha9` is, in fact installed.

So I googled this and found another solution: where I can type this into terminal:

`cd /Users/Me/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin` and
`./sdkmanager "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.0-alpha9"`

This failed, even though again it says it is installed.

This is my current `Gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        T {
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.myapp.com'
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 39
        versionName 'Version 39'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}    

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.9.2.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() // here
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() // and here
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I am assuming these issues are caused because I am trying to edit an old app on a new version of android studio and Gradle.

How can I either

- Update the app to the newest versions without having to redesign/reprogram it
- Step down a few versions of AS so everything runs and complies appropriately.

Comment: Replace `compile` with `implementation`. Then, there are so many steps to do... replace all deprecated classes, migration to `Androidx`, implement `Androidx` `AppCompat dependencies`...